# Cast Strings in nested json to numeric

Tags: json, postgresql

unfurtnally at the moment I have a jsonb coulmn where numerics are stored as strings.
I need a function to cast these strings to numerics

This was a try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_strings_to_numbers(data jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    result jsonb;
BEGIN
    IF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'string' THEN
        BEGIN
            result := to_jsonb(data::numeric);
        EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
            result := data;
        END;
    ELSIF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'array' THEN
        SELECT jsonb_agg(convert_strings_to_numbers(value))
        INTO result
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) AS value;
    ELSIF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'object' THEN
        SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, convert_strings_to_numbers(value))
        INTO result
        FROM jsonb_each(data);
    ELSE
        result := data;
    END IF;
    RETURN result;
END;
$$;
```

But they remain as strings:

```
SELECT convert_strings_to_numbers('{"abc": {"def": "232323", "efas": "20232326", "dwadwa": "gef"}}'::jsonb);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/fvPRc9Cy

Does anyone know how to solve that the result of the function is this:

```
{"abc": {"def": 232323, "efas": 20232326, "dwadwa": "gef"}
```

EDIT:

I would need to transfer timestamps and dates aswell.
I used the code from Zegarek.

it works for numbers/dates/timestamps but not for strings:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_strings(data jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $f$
DECLARE
    result jsonb;
BEGIN
    IF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'string' THEN
        BEGIN
            result := to_jsonb(REPLACE((data#>>'{}'),',','.')::numeric);
        EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_text_representation THEN
          BEGIN
            result := to_jsonb(to_timestamp((data#>>'{}'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone);
          EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_text_representation THEN
           result := data;
          end;
        END;
    ELSIF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'array' THEN
        SELECT jsonb_agg(convert_strings(value))
        INTO result
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) AS value;
    ELSIF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'object' THEN
        SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, convert_strings(value))
        INTO result
        FROM jsonb_each(data);
    ELSE
        result := data;
    END IF;
    RETURN result;
END;
$f$;
```

Working:

```
select 
convert_strings('{"abc":{"def": "232.323","mydate":"26.02.2024","myts":"26.02.2024 11:37:37"}}'::jsonb);
```

not Working:

```
select 
convert_strings('{"abc":{"def": "232.323","mydate":"26.02.2024","myts":"26.02.2024 11:37:37","dwadwa": "gef"}}'::jsonb);
```

Comment: You reopened the thread to add that you did the exact same thing again: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_iSTmsYp). The new error is `22007`/`invalid_datetime_format` - my answer already showed how to catch it, look it up and add handling for the specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your catch-all block swallowed the error:

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot cast jsonb string to type numeric
> ```

That complains about this line:

```sql
result := to_jsonb(data::numeric);
```

And it doesn't concern just the `"gef"` - it's raised for every single value you have there - that's because [`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) [outputs `jsonb` type for each value](https://dbfiddle.uk/kpH2KrfJ). If you instead extract and unwrap the value with [`#>>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) first, it'll work just fine:

```sql
result := to_jsonb((data#>>'{}')::numeric);
```

When you try to rely on `exception` block, it's best to first make sure you're [trapping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) the specific thing you wish to handle. According to [the table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html), in your case that'd be error `22P02` or `invalid_text_representation` (the `"gef"` case). [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/NJrHj_iU)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_strings(data jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $f$
DECLARE result jsonb;
BEGIN
    IF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'string' THEN
        BEGIN
            result := to_jsonb(REPLACE((data#>>'{}'),',','.')::numeric);
        EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_text_representation THEN
          BEGIN
            result := to_jsonb(to_timestamp((data#>>'{}'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp);
          EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_datetime_format THEN 
           result := data;
          END;
        END;
    ELSIF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'array' THEN
        SELECT jsonb_agg(convert_strings(value))
        INTO result
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) AS value;
    ELSIF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'object' THEN
        SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, convert_strings(value))
        INTO result
        FROM jsonb_each(data);
    ELSE
        result := data;
    END IF;
    RETURN result;
END $f$;
```

```sql
select 
convert_strings('{"abc":{"def": "232.323",
                         "mydate":"26.02.2024",
                         "myts":"26.02.2024 11:37:37",
                         "dwadwa": "gef"}}'::jsonb);
```

| convert_strings |
| --- |
| {"abc": {"def": 232.323, "myts": "2024-02-26T11:37:37", "dwadwa": "gef", "mydate": "2024-02-26T00:00:00"}} |

You can identify the error you happened to catch by the means of `when others then` by inspecting `SQLSTATE` variable in the `exception` block (save it to a debug table, print to log). Once you know that's what gets thrown, change `when others then` to `when your_specific_exception then` to avoid obfuscating other problems like this.